# T-SQL regular expression :: remove everything before a certain symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

The values in my column [Status] are represented this way:

```
Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=782, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQLS
Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=782, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQ
Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQ
```

I just would like to select everything after the `Collation=`

so I use:

```
SELECT right([Status], len([Status]) - charindex('=', [Status]))
FROM MyDatabase
```

but this way the result is just everything after the first `=` and I have this:

```
ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=782, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQLS
ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=782, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQ
ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQ
```

But I want to have everything after the last `=`:

```
Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQLS
Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQ
Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQ
```

How to do that?

Comment: Ummm, so search for `Collation=` rather than `=` in your `CHARINDEX()`?

Comment: Also, using `STUFF` to remove the start of the string might be an easier solution.

Comment: Though, really the problem is you are storing denormalised data in your database. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: According to your example I'd say your string is lacking some chars: the collation should end after `Latin1_General_CI_AS` - the `SQLS` and `SQ` most certainly belong to the next information in your string...

Comment: @Larnu: this results are collected by the official Microsoft tool "Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit": https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7826 . I will send them an e-mail saying they are not following best practices ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want everything after the last `=`, you can simply use:

```
select t.*, 
       right(t.status, charindex('=', reverse(t.status)) - 1)
from t ;
```

If you want the "argument" to "collation", the simplest method is probably `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, c.collation
from t outer apply
     (select s2.value as collation
      from string_split(t.status, ',') s cross apply
           string_spit(s.value, '=') s2
      where trim(s.value) like 'Collation%'
     ) c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98f76adb6f1529451850e0ea4da981b1) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I guess the `SQLS` and `SQ` belong to the next information, not the collation. However, if you want "everything after the collation" you would have to modify your query just a little:

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(200) = 'Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=782, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQLS'
SELECT right(@x, len(@x) - charindex('Collation=', @x) - 9)
```

Comment: what does the value 9 do?

Comment: It removes the remaining characters of `Collation=` from the result

Comment: thanks for clarifying.  I suggest you put that fact in your content or do -len("Collation=") for understandability